# Math discrete: Proof by induction of harmonic serie

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction, harmonic-functions

I need to prove by induction the following. The left hand side of the inequality is basically a harmonic serie where $H(1065^k)$. I've been able to complete this problem with $H(2^k)\ge 1 + \frac k2$, but can't seen to complete this problem...

$$\sum_{k=1}^{1065^k} \frac 1k \ge 1 + \frac {1064}{1065} k$$

Comment: Having $k$ as a dummy variable and also as a part of the answer is bad practice. Better to write $$\sum_{r=1}^{1065^k}{1\over r}\ge1+{1064\over1065}k$$

Comment: Can you show $$\sum_{1065^{k-1}+1}^{1065^k}{1\over r}\ge{1064\over1065}$$

Comment: I actually wrote i=1 1/i I have no idea why I wrote k on both sides haha

Comment: I can show $$ \ge \frac{1}{1065}$$ but I don't know about $$ \frac {1064}{1065} $$

Comment: How many terms are in the sum, and what's the smallest of those terms?

Comment: 1065^k terms because 1065^k - 1065^(k-1) = 1065^k and smallest is 1/1065^k

Comment: $1065^k-1065^{k-1}$ is not $1065^k$.

Comment: wait you are right right it's 1064 x 1065^(x - 1) omg

Comment: aaaaah ty wait you are 200 IQ

Comment: Let me encourage you to write it up & post it as an answer.

Comment: Why not do it today?